# align-self: flex-end not working in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using "milligram.css" ([a micro CSS framework](https://milligram.github.io/#grids)).

I want to align a DIV inside a column to the bottom.

But nothing happens, the DIV is always aligned top.

https://jsfiddle.net/fb8ydfcy/3/

```css
.column {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.col-bottom {
  border: 3px solid blue;
}


/*!
 * Milligram v1.1.0
 * http://milligram.github.io
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2016 CJ Patoilo
 * Licensed under the MIT license
*/

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  color: #606c76;
  font-family: "Roboto", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

blockquote {
  border-left: 0.3rem solid #d1d1d1;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
}

blockquote *:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

.button,
button,
input[type='button'],
input[type='reset'],
input[type='submit'] {
  background-color: #9b4dca;
  border: 0.1rem solid #9b4dca;
  border-radius: 0.4rem;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  height: 3.8rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
  line-height: 3.8rem;
  padding: 0 3rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.button:hover,
.button:focus,
button:hover,
button:focus,
input[type='button']:hover,
input[type='button']:focus,
input[type='reset']:hover,
input[type='reset']:focus,
input[type='submit']:hover,
input[type='submit']:focus {
  background-color: #606c76;
  border-color: #606c76;
  color: #fff;
  outline: 0;
}

.button.button-disabled,
.button[disabled],
button.button-disabled,
button[disabled],
input[type='button'].button-disabled,
input[type='button'][disabled],
input[type='reset'].button-disabled,
input[type='reset'][disabled],
input[type='submit'].button-disabled,
input[type='submit'][disabled] {
  opacity: 0.5;
  cursor: default;
}

.button.button-disabled:hover,
.button.button-disabled:focus,
.button[disabled]:hover,
.button[disabled]:focus,
button.button-disabled:hover,
button.button-disabled:focus,
button[disabled]:hover,
button[disabled]:focus,
input[type='button'].button-disabled:hover,
input[type='button'].button-disabled:focus,
input[type='button'][disabled]:hover,
input[type='button'][disabled]:focus,
input[type='reset'].button-disabled:hover,
input[type='reset'].button-disabled:focus,
input[type='reset'][disabled]:hover,
input[type='reset'][disabled]:focus,
input[type='submit'].button-disabled:hover,
input[type='submit'].button-disabled:focus,
input[type='submit'][disabled]:hover,
input[type='submit'][disabled]:focus {
  background-color: #9b4dca;
  border-color: #9b4dca;
}

.button.button-outline,
button.button-outline,
input[type='button'].button-outline,
input[type='reset'].button-outline,
input[type='submit'].button-outline {
  color: #9b4dca;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.button.button-outline:hover,
.button.button-outline:focus,
button.button-outline:hover,
button.button-outline:focus,
input[type='button'].button-outline:hover,
input[type='button'].button-outline:focus,
input[type='reset'].button-outline:hover,
input[type='reset'].button-outline:focus,
input[type='submit'].button-outline:hover,
input[type='submit'].button-outline:focus {
  color: #606c76;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: #606c76;
}

.button.button-outline.button-disabled:hover,
.button.button-outline.button-disabled:focus,
.button.button-outline[disabled]:hover,
.button.button-outline[disabled]:focus,
button.button-outline.button-disabled:hover,
button.button-outline.button-disabled:focus,
button.button-outline[disabled]:hover,
button.button-outline[disabled]:focus,
input[type='button'].button-outline.button-disabled:hover,
input[type='button'].button-outline.button-disabled:focus,
input[type='button'].button-outline[disabled]:hover,
input[type='button'].button-outline[disabled]:focus,
input[type='reset'].button-outline.button-disabled:hover,
input[type='reset'].button-outline.button-disabled:focus,
input[type='reset'].button-outline[disabled]:hover,
input[type='reset'].button-outline[disabled]:focus,
input[type='submit'].button-outline.button-disabled:hover,
input[type='submit'].button-outline.button-disabled:focus,
input[type='submit'].button-outline[disabled]:hover,
input[type='submit'].button-outline[disabled]:focus {
  color: #9b4dca;
  border-color: inherit;
}

.button.button-clear,
button.button-clear,
input[type='button'].button-clear,
input[type='reset'].button-clear,
input[type='submit'].button-clear {
  color: #9b4dca;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
}

.button.button-clear:hover,
.button.button-clear:focus,
button.button-clear:hover,
button.button-clear:focus,
input[type='button'].button-clear:hover,
input[type='button'].button-clear:focus,
input[type='reset'].button-clear:hover,
input[type='reset'].button-clear:focus,
input[type='submit'].button-clear:hover,
input[type='submit'].button-clear:focus {
  color: #606c76;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
}

.button.button-clear.button-disabled:hover,
.button.button-clear.button-disabled:focus,
.button.button-clear[disabled]:hover,
.button.button-clear[disabled]:focus,
button.button-clear.button-disabled:hover,
button.button-clear.button-disabled:focus,
button.button-clear[disabled]:hover,
button.button-clear[disabled]:focus,
input[type='button'].button-clear.button-disabled:hover,
input[type='button'].button-clear.button-disabled:focus,
input[type='button'].button-clear[disabled]:hover,
input[type='button'].button-clear[disabled]:focus,
input[type='reset'].button-clear.button-disabled:hover,
input[type='reset'].button-clear.button-disabled:focus,
input[type='reset'].button-clear[disabled]:hover,
input[type='reset'].button-clear[disabled]:focus,
input[type='submit'].button-clear.button-disabled:hover,
input[type='submit'].button-clear.button-disabled:focus,
input[type='submit'].button-clear[disabled]:hover,
input[type='submit'].button-clear[disabled]:focus {
  color: #9b4dca;
}

code {
  background: #f4f5f6;
  border-radius: 0.4rem;
  font-size: 86%;
  padding: 0.2rem 0.5rem;
  margin: 0 0.2rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

pre {
  background: #f4f5f6;
  border-left: 0.3rem solid #9b4dca;
  font-family: "Menlo", "Consolas", "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono", "DejaVu Sans Mono", "Monaco", monospace;
}

pre>code {
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 0;
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  white-space: pre;
}

hr {
  border: 0;
  border-top: 0.1rem solid #f4f5f6;
  margin-bottom: 3.5rem;
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

input[type='email'],
input[type='number'],
input[type='password'],
input[type='search'],
input[type='tel'],
input[type='text'],
input[type='url'],
textarea,
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0.1rem solid #d1d1d1;
  border-radius: 0.4rem;
  box-shadow: none;
  height: 3.8rem;
  padding: 0.6rem 1rem;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type='email']:focus,
input[type='number']:focus,
input[type='password']:focus,
input[type='search']:focus,
input[type='tel']:focus,
input[type='text']:focus,
input[type='url']:focus,
textarea:focus,
select:focus {
  border: 0.1rem solid #9b4dca;
  outline: 0;
}

select {
  padding: 0.6rem 3rem 0.6rem 1rem;
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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) center right no-repeat;
}

select:focus {
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}

textarea {
  padding-bottom: 0.6rem;
  padding-top: 0.6rem;
  min-height: 6.5rem;
}

label,
legend {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

fieldset {
  border-width: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

input[type='checkbox'],
input[type='radio'] {
  display: inline;
}

.label-inline {
  font-weight: normal;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 112rem;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.row .row-wrap {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.row .row-no-padding {
  padding: 0;
}

.row .row-no-padding>.column {
  padding: 0;
}

.row .row-top {
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.row .row-bottom {
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.row .row-center {
  align-items: center;
}

.row .row-stretch {
  align-items: stretch;
}

.row .row-baseline {
  align-items: baseline;
}

.row .column {
  display: block;
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.row .column .col-top {
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.row .column .col-bottom {
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.row .column .col-center {
  align-self: center;
}

.row .column.column-offset-10 {
  margin-left: 10%;
}

.row .column.column-offset-20 {
  margin-left: 20%;
}

.row .column.column-offset-25 {
  margin-left: 25%;
}

.row .column.column-offset-33,
.row .column.column-offset-34 {
  margin-left: 33.3333%;
}

.row .column.column-offset-50 {
  margin-left: 50%;
}

.row .column.column-offset-66,
.row .column.column-offset-67 {
  margin-left: 66.6666%;
}

.row .column.column-offset-75 {
  margin-left: 75%;
}

.row .column.column-offset-80 {
  margin-left: 80%;
}

.row .column.column-offset-90 {
  margin-left: 90%;
}

.row .column.column-10 {
  flex: 0 0 10%;
  max-width: 10%;
}

.row .column.column-20 {
  flex: 0 0 20%;
  max-width: 20%;
}

.row .column.column-25 {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
}

.row .column.column-33,
.row .column.column-34 {
  flex: 0 0 33.3333%;
  max-width: 33.3333%;
}

.row .column.column-40 {
  flex: 0 0 40%;
  max-width: 40%;
}

.row .column.column-50 {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.row .column.column-60 {
  flex: 0 0 60%;
  max-width: 60%;
}

.row .column.column-66,
.row .column.column-67 {
  flex: 0 0 66.6666%;
  max-width: 66.6666%;
}

.row .column.column-75 {
  flex: 0 0 75%;
  max-width: 75%;
}

.row .column.column-80 {
  flex: 0 0 80%;
  max-width: 80%;
}

.row .column.column-90 {
  flex: 0 0 90%;
  max-width: 90%;
}

@media (min-width: 40rem) {
  .row {
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-left: -1rem;
    width: calc(100% + 2.0rem);
  }
  .row .column {
    margin-bottom: inherit;
    padding: 0 1rem;
  }
}

a {
  color: #9b4dca;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #606c76;
}

dl,
ol,
ul {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

dl ul,
dl ol,
ol ul,
ol ol,
ul ul,
ul ol {
  font-size: 90%;
  margin: 1.5rem 0 1.5rem 3rem;
}

dl {
  list-style: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: circle inside;
}

ol {
  list-style: decimal inside;
}

dt,
dd,
li {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.button,
button {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

input,
textarea,
select,
fieldset {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

pre,
blockquote,
dl,
figure,
table,
p,
ul,
ol,
form {
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

th,
td {
  border-bottom: 0.1rem solid #e1e1e1;
  padding: 1.2rem 1.5rem;
  text-align: left;
}

th:first-child,
td:first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
}

th:last-child,
td:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}

p {
  margin-top: 0;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  margin-top: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
  letter-spacing: -0.1rem;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 3.6rem;
  letter-spacing: -0.1rem;
  line-height: 1.25;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  letter-spacing: -0.1rem;
  line-height: 1.3;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  letter-spacing: -0.08rem;
  line-height: 1.35;
}

h5 {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  letter-spacing: -0.05rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

h6 {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

@media (min-width: 40rem) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 5rem;
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: 4.2rem;
  }
  h3 {
    font-size: 3.6rem;
  }
  h4 {
    font-size: 3rem;
  }
  h5 {
    font-size: 2.4rem;
  }
  h6 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
}

.float-right {
  float: right;
}

.float-left {
  float: left;
}

.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
}

.clearfix:after,
.clearfix:before {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://milligram.io/css/milligram.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

  <article class="entry">

    <h2>
      <?php the_title(); ?>
    </h2>

    <?php the_content(); ?>

    <div class="container-fluid container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">column
          <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        </div>
        <!-- should be aligned to the bottom -->
        <div class="column">
          <div class="col-bottom">column</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </article>

</section>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're applying flex properties to a child of a `block` element. Such properties will be ignored because you're in a [***block formatting context***](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting).

Switch from `display: block` to `display: flex` to establish a [***flex formatting context***](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#flex-containers).

Instead of this:

```
.row .column {
  display: block;
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Try this:

```
.row .column {
  display: flex; /* adjusted */
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

For an explanation of `align-self` and other *cross axis* alignment properties, see here:

- [How does flex-wrap work with align-self, align-items and align-content?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42613359/3597276)

To learn about flex alignment along the *main axis*, see here:

- [In CSS Flexbox, why are there no "justify-items" and "justify-self" properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276)